# Google Sheets: two sets of dependent drop down lists on same sheet and same script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Three hours ago I didn't know how to do a dependent drop-down list at all. Now, I have a data validated column that, when choosing the data, will give a drop-down for the next cell over. However, I would like to do this twice. The problem is, I don't know how to duplicate it in the script.  [This is how I even got this far](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-I8Z4nTDak)

[This is the link to my Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w0WaAblUaI199IwYUZt43CMlz_7R95rBtNrF7M8vXp4/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is the code I had before trying to work on the FEEDBACK columns. The TECHNICAL columns work as intended:

```
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Raw Data");
var wsTechnical = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Drop Downs - Technical");
var technical = wsTechnical.getRange(2, 1,wsTechnical.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();



function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  if(wsName == "Raw Data" && c === 6 &&  r > 2){

    if(val === ""){
      ws.getRange(r, 7).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r, 7).clearDataValidations();
    } else {
      ws.getRange(r, 7).clearContent();
      var filteredTechnical = technical.filter(function(t){ return t[0] === val });
      var listToApply = filteredTechnical.map(function(t){ return t[1] });
      var cell = ws.getRange(r, 7);
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
    }
  }
}


function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){

  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list)
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();

  cell.setDataValidation(rule)
}
```

This is how I changed it in hopes that it would create the same flow for the FEEDBACK columns but it changed absolutely nothing; the TECHNICAL columns still work as intended but the FEEDBACK columns do not
:

```
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Raw Data");
var wsFeedback = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Drop Downs - Feedback");
var feedback = wsFeedback.getRange(2, 1,wsFeedback.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();
var wsTechnical = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Drop Downs - Technical");
var technical = wsTechnical.getRange(2, 1,wsTechnical.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();

function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCel1.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  if(wsName == "Raw Data" && c === 4 &&  r > 2){

    if(val === ""){
      ws.getRange(r, 5).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r, 5).clearDataValidations();
    } else {
      ws.getRange(r, 5).clearContent();
      var filteredFeedback = feedback.filter(function(f){ return f[0] === val });
      var listToApply = filteredFeedback.map(function(f){ return f[1] });
      var cell = ws.getRange(r, 5);
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
    }
  }
}

function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  if(wsName == "Raw Data" && c === 6 &&  r > 2){

    if(val === ""){
      ws.getRange(r, 7).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r, 7).clearDataValidations();
    } else {
      ws.getRange(r, 7).clearContent();
      var filteredTechnical = technical.filter(function(t){ return t[0] === val });
      var listToApply = filteredTechnical.map(function(t){ return t[1] });
      var cell = ws.getRange(r, 7);
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
    }
  }
}


function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){

  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list)
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();

  cell.setDataValidation(rule)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: Again, I know close to nothing about scripts and well... all of this. If willing, please dumb down your answer for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with your `onEdit(e)` functions.

When Google detects that an edit was made, it will call the  `onEdit()` function, but, if there are two of them, it won't call both, just the first one.

to fix this, do the following with your code:

```
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Raw Data");
var wsFeedback = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Drop Downs - Feedback");
var feedback = wsFeedback.getRange(2, 1,wsFeedback.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();

var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Raw Data");
var wsTechnical = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Drop Downs - Technical");
var technical = wsTechnical.getRange(2, 1,wsTechnical.getLastRow()-1,2).getValues();

function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  if(wsName == "Raw Data" && c === 4 &&  r > 2){

    if(val === ""){
      ws.getRange(r, 5).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r, 5).clearDataValidations();
    } else {
      ws.getRange(r, 5).clearContent();
      var filteredFeedback = feedback.filter(function(f){ return f[0] === val });
      var listToApply = filteredFeedback.map(function(f){ return f[1] });
      var cell = ws.getRange(r, 5);
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
    }
  } else if(wsName == "Raw Data" && c === 6 &&  r > 2){
    if(val === ""){
      ws.getRange(r, 7).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r, 7).clearDataValidations();
    } else {
      ws.getRange(r, 7).clearContent();
      var filteredTechnical = technical.filter(function(t){ return t[0] === val });
      var listToApply = filteredTechnical.map(function(t){ return t[1] });
      var cell = ws.getRange(r, 7);
      applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
    }
  }
}

function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){

  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
  .newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInList(list)
  .setAllowInvalid(false)
  .build();

  cell.setDataValidation(rule)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No worries. Here to help. :)